# How to uninstall Firebird from Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, firebird

I’ve found [this script from Paul Beach](http://paulbeachsblog.blogspot.com/2008/02/firebird-and-macosx-uninstalls.html), but I want to know if there is a better way (maybe a script included in the installation).

Comment: Suggest move to SuperUser; question not programming-related.

Comment: According to FAQ, questions related to tools used by programmers or related to software development in some way are valid, that’s why I posted here since I and a lot of programmers also use Firebird for development.

Answer (score 1):

The script is modifying environment outside of user's home directory: removing installed frameworks, global groups etc. Proper way how do this would be dedicated uninstaller. With no uninstaller available, something like that script is probably best / simplest solution.

For most applications, utilities like AppZapper handle unistallation + clean up ~/Library/ subfolders. Worth trying out for other situations - http://www.appzapper.com/, but in this case will likely not be sufficient.

Comment: AppZapper does nothing in terms of cleaning up extra users/groups, startup items, Frameworks, LaunchDaemons and Receipts which is what this script does.

Comment: You are right, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The script you found is safe and doing all the cleaning to be done.

If you copied it under:

```
/tmp/firebird_uninstall
```

you have to fire it with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /tmp/firebird_uninstall
```